# Realizar join sobre una tabla dependiendo del valor de un campo

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta en `Mysql` y según la columna `type` de mi tabla reportes, hacer un `JOIN` a una tabla u a otra.

**Reportes:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En `type` se almacena el tipo de elemento al que se reporta que puede ser `channel` o `group`. Según el tipo de elemento al que se ha reportado pretendo hacer un `JOIN` a la tabla de `groups` o `channels` para sacar el título y demás datos.

La estructura de `channels` y `groups` es la misma.

Hasta ahora he intentado hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT count(*) as contador, type, `id_type`, b.title, IF(STRCMP(report.type,'group'), 'groups', 'channels') as m  FROM `report` JOIN m as b ON report.id_type = b.id GROUP BY `id_type`, `type` ORDER BY contador DESC;
```

Pero me dice que la tabla `m` no existe. Tambien intenté poner el `IF` de esta manera:

```
SELECT count(*) as contador, type, `id_type`, b.title FROM `report` JOIN IF(STRCMP(report.type,'group'), 'groups', 'channels') as b ON report.id_type = b.id GROUP BY `id_type`, `type` ORDER BY contador DESC;
```

Y me devuelve:

> 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'IF(STRCMP(report.type,'group'), 'groups', 'channels') as b ON report.id_type = b' en la linea 1

Comment: Aunque te pueda proponer una solución, no tiene sentido que tu consulta devuelva `b.title` cuando no incluyes este campo en el `group by`. Creo que la pregunta sería mas clara si incluyes ejemplos de datos, y el resultado deseado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este tipo de inner join condicional se puede hacer con 2 left joins y algunas condiciones adicionales en la claúsula `WHERE` de esta manera:

```
select count(*) as contador,
       r.type,
       r.id_type,
       case when g.id is not null 
            then g.title
            else c.title
       end as title -- aquí aún tienes un problema...
  from report r
  left join groups g
    on g.id = r.id_type
   and r.type = 'group'
  left join channels c
    on c.id = r.id_type
   and r.type = 'channel'
 where g.id is not null
    or c.id is not null
 group by r.id_type,
          r.type
 order by contador
```

El único problema, como ya te comenté, es que estás tratando de devolver un valor para el campo `title` sin aplicarle una función de agregación, lo que no tiene sentido si no incluyes el `title` en la claúsula `GROUP BY`. La consecuencia de esto es que no hay manera de saber de cual registro se sacará el valor para `title`. Eso es algo que te tocará definir y arreglar. Sin tener más detalles en cuanto a tu modelo de datos, no te pueda ayudar más.

Comment: Muchas gracias sstan, para lo que quería hacer me funciona perfecto :)

Answer (score 1):

otra forma de resolver el problema, pero como dice el compañero Sstan tienes un problema que resolver en el campo title:

```
SELECT count(*) as contador,r.id_type, r.type, COALESCE(g.title, c.title) as title  FROM report r
LEFT JOIN groups as g ON r.id_type = g.id
LEFT JOIN channels as c ON r.id_type = c.id 
WHERE (CASE WHEN r.type='group' THEN g.id is not null ELSE c.id is not null END)
GROUP BY r.id_type, r.type
ORDER BY contador DESC;
```

una posible solución podría ser agrupar los campos de titulo y mostrarlos separados por ',' para esto deberías cambiar en el select `COALESCE(g.title, c.title)` por    `COALESCE(group_concat(g.title SEPARATOR ','), group_concat(c.title SEPARATOR ',')) as title`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!